# Under what conditions does $\mathcal{P}(\cup A) = A$ hold

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying ZF axiomatic set theory and I've encountered this question:

> Under what conditions does $\mathcal{P}(\cup A) = A$ holds?

I easily proved that $A \subseteq\mathcal{P}(\cup A)$ and now I'm wondering whether the other inclusion holds.

I first noted that it holds for $A = \{\varnothing\}$ and does not hold for $A = \varnothing$. But the first one is the only case?

I tried to suppose that $A\neq \varnothing$ and that $A$ has an element other than $\phi$. Taking an such element, say $a = \{a_i\}$ in $A$, we have that every $a_i$ is in $\cup A$ so that any subset $\{a_{k_i}\}$ of $a$ must a subset of $\cup A$, that is, $\mathcal{P}(a)\subseteq \cup A$. I think I must arrive at a contradiction from here but I don't know what to conclude from this.

Any help will be appreciated. (Obs.: I don't know for sure which of the two tags of set theory I must choose, once this question is not so elementary in the sense of common set theory used in math. I entered both but feel free to change if you know what is the correct one).

Comment: For one thing, since $\bigcup A\in\mathcal P(\bigcup A),$ a necessary condition is that $\bigcup A\in A.$ Hmm. Isn't that equivalent to saying that $A$ has a greatest element under the $\subseteq$ ordering?

Comment: @bof: Actually, it says more. It says that $\varnothing\in A$, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if $\mathcal P(\bigcup A)=A$, then in particular, $A=\mathcal P(X)$ for some set $X$, which happens to be $\bigcup A$. So that condition is necessary.

But if you check closely, you will also find that it is sufficient. This is why $\{\varnothing\}$ satisfies this, being $\mathcal P(\varnothing)$, but $\varnothing$ does not.