# Power Set of Unary Union

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

It is easy to see that for every set $A$, we have $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\bigcup A)$, where $\bigcup A$ is the **unary union** of $A$. However, I actually have no idea about the reverse inclusion -  under what conditions does $A \supseteq \mathcal{P}(\bigcup A)$ hold?

My suspicion is that this does not hold for any set $A$ in general, but I cannot prove this. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** As indicated in one of the comments, $A=\mathcal{P}(X)$ for some set $X$ is both a necessary and sufficient condition for $A = \mathcal{P}(\bigcup A)$.

Firstly, if equality holds, then $A$ is indeed a power set (of $\bigcup A$).

On the other hand, suppose $A = \mathcal{P}(X)$ holds. We claim that for all sets $X$, $X = \bigcup \mathcal{P}(X)$.
To see why, note that $X \in \mathcal{P}(X)$, and every other element in $P(X)$ is a subset of $X$.

Hence, by the above lemma, $\mathcal{P}(\bigcup A)=\mathcal{P}\left(\bigcup \mathcal{P}(X)\right) =  \mathcal{P}(X) =A $.

Comment: Here is the referenced link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903232/under-what-conditions-does-mathcalp-cup-a-a-hold